# using Class<?> to represent an interface

Tags: class, interface

I hope the title accurately represents what I'm asking here. For my assignment here, I have a `Speakerphone` object, which is a singleton, and two interfaces, `Listener` and `Talker` with which `Speakerphone` needs to communicate.

There are two `shoutMessage` methods, the second of which takes a Class object as a parameter. Here's where I'm confused - I don't know if the "Class object" in the instructions is referring to the `Listener` interface, or the `Speakerphone` object. Can anyone tell me if the code in this method is correct, based on the instructions here?

```
public class Speakerphone extends Object {
    private static Speakerphone sSpeaker = null;
    private static HashSet<Listener> mListener = new HashSet<Listener>();
    private static HashSet<Talker> mTalker = new HashSet<Talker>();


    private Speakerphone() {
    }
    /*
     * get
     *
     * @return the singleton instance of Speakerphone (Speakerphone)
     */
    /************************************************
     *  ASSIGNMENT:
     *  Implement the get method
    /************************************************/
    public static Speakerphone get(){
        if (sSpeaker == null){
            sSpeaker = new Speakerphone();
        }
        return sSpeaker;
    }

/*
     * shoutMessage
     *
     * Sends the message to all of the Listeners tracked by Speakerphone
     *
     * @param talker a Talker whose message will be sent (Talker)
     * @return nothing
     */
    /************************************************
     *  ASSIGNMENT:
     *  Implement the shoutMessage method
    /************************************************/
    public void shoutMessage(Talker talker){
        Iterator<Talker> talkIterator = mTalker.iterator();
        while(talkIterator.hasNext())
        talkIterator.next().getMessage();
       }

    /*
     * shoutMessage
     *
     * Sends the message to all of the Listeners which are instances of
     * the cls parameter
     *
     * @param talker a Talker whose message will be sent (Talker)
     * @param cls a Class object representing the type which the Listener
     *            should extend from in order to receive the message (Class)
     * @return nothing
     *
     * HINT: see Class.isAssignableFrom()
     *       http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)
     */
    /************************************************
     *  ASSIGNMENT:
     *  Implement the shoutMessage method
    /************************************************/
    public void shoutMessage(Talker talker, Class<?> cls){

        if (Listener.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)){
        Iterator<Talker> talkIterator = mTalker.iterator();
        while(talkIterator.hasNext())
        talkIterator.next().getMessage();
       }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the class parameter in the `shoutMessage` method appears to be there so you can select out only listeners of a certain type.  `Class` in Java is an object that describes a data type - a meta of meta so to speak.

Based on the comments in the code it looks like your `shoutMessage` method might be doing the opposite of what you want.  Here's what I think it needs to do (based on the comments of the method):

1. Iterate through all of the listeners in your mListener HashSet.  For each listener in the HashSet, do the following
2. As you iterate through, use `Listener.class.isAssignableFrom` to determine if the current listener is of class `cls`.
3. If it is of the type `cls` then call `talker.getMessage()` and pass that message to the current listener (by calling "receiveMessage" or "on" or whatever function is defined in your Listener interface).
4. If it is not of the type `cls` then ignore.